# BitmapDecoder.CreatAsync(RandomAccessStream) throwing Exception

Tags: c#, web-applications, .net-core, task

I'm creating a `BitmapDecoder` using `await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync` method in a  `.NET Core Web Application` Project but I'm getting this exception

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   System.Threading.Tasks.AsyncCausalityTracer from assembly mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

The same method works in a simple console application and gives expected results.

`var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(randomAccessStream);`

Comment: didnt you mix up targeting frameworks for ex. full 4.5 instead of core?

Comment: ```<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>```

Comment: Can you please provide what nuget package you are using or implementation of your BitmapDecoder.

Comment: ```Microsoft.AspNetCore.App```

```Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design Version=2.1.2```

```System.Device.Location.Portable Version=1.0.0```

```System.Runtime.InteropServices Version=4.3.0```

```System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime Version=4.3.0```